# How to get my own images do not work for this liquid slider?

Tags: javascript, canvas, slider

Any image I try big or small will just load blank or black with this slider. https://codepen.io/TurkAysenur/pen/YzYqdyb

```
const images = [
 "my image url here",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468436385273-8abca6dfd8d3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1705&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493707553966-283afac8c358?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
 "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508189860359-777d945909ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
];
```

I have tried different sizes, uploading to different servers etc.

Is there something I am missing that is required of the image for it to work on this type of slider?

I have tried different sizes, uploading to different servers etc.

Comment: What is the url you are using? Where is the image stored in relation to the rest of the code? Have you checked in your browser devtools to see if there is a loading error? My guess would be that you are running into a CORS issue.

Comment: You were right. It is a CORS issue.